# Unity - Inject object of different classes for the same interface in a same class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have one interface: IFoo
Two classes implementing that interface: FooOne and FooTwo

And one classes ClassOne  receiving an IFoo parameter in the constructor.

I have two methods MethodOne and methodTwo in Classone.

If i call MethodOne I need the object FooOne in Classone

If i call MethodTwo I need the object FooTwo in Classone

How I configure unity so ClassOne receives a FooOne instance for MethodOne call and ClassOne receives a FooTwo for MethodTwo call using only one container?.

The main condition is I need to create one object at a time either FooOne or FooTwo.

Comment: Whatever MethodOne and MethodTwo are doing should be placed in the Foo classes I believe.

Comment: I have a  requirement like this scenario.

Comment: Can you show the `ClassOne` class?

Answer (score 1):

Using named registration:

```
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooOne>("one");
container.RegisterType<IFoo, FooTwo>("two");

//...

class Classone
{
    IFoo MethodOne()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IFoo>("one");
    }

    IFoo MethodTwo()
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IFoo>("two");
    }
}
```